# How do I display an image located at google drive in a GAS UI?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to display an image (**located at my Google Drive account** and with link open to view to everyone with the link) in an UI with this code:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(150).setWidth(250);
var msg = "Suas configurações foram salvas. ;-) ";
app.setTitle("Deu certo!");
app.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(app.createLabel(msg)));
app.add(app.createImage("https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ItQgqkEUm8VVhwUTBUMkc3a1E/edit?usp=sharing"));
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
doc.show(app);
```

But it didn't work (the image isn't displayed):

[image]

Comment: Bryan's answer is right, don't forget you have a setPixelSize method  to best fit the image in your Ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://googledrive.com/host/PUBLIC_FOLDER_ID/FILE_NAME`

Image and it's folder need to be shared as public on the web.