# Using an image stored in Google Drive in GAS HTML

Tags: html, image, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to know if I can incorporate an image I host on my Google Drive (shared publicly to the web) into an HTML page.

Using something like this doesn't work (although you can navigate to that link yourself):

```
<image src="http://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByarjphAWhEvM1p4d0hiTGJOeW8" />
```

-

I have found this answer, but it doesn't seem to be working:

[AppsScript- Using an image from Google Drive in HtmlService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249531/appsscript-using-an-image-from-google-drive-in-htmlservice)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ? it works in UiApp and in HTMLService

```
https://googledrive.com/host/YOUR_FILE_ID
```

Image needs to be shared as public on the web.

[Example :](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzxk2W1grU1QY0qdo9wAv-2de_T6XbSluBE6_xXt0433a_tetw2/exec)

```
<img src= "https://googledrive.com/host/0B3qSFd3iikE3TUFFLTZiMWVhYjVkLThhNDctNDdhNC04MjI0LTkzZTc5NDRmNjc1Yw" >
```

(taken from this post : [How do I display an image located at google drive in a GAS UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110388/how-do-i-display-an-image-located-at-google-drive-in-a-gas-ui/25111382#25111382))